# How to start Spring Boot app in Spock Integration Test

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, spring-boot, spock

What is the best way to run an integration test (e.g., [`@IntegrationTest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/test/IntegrationTest.html)) with Spock? I would like to bootstrap the whole Spring Boot application and execute some HTTP calls to test the whole functionality.

*Spring Boot app starts in this working JUnit test (first the app runs and then the tests execute)*:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyServer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
class MyTest {
   RestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

   @Test
   public void testDataRoutingWebSocketToHttp() {
      def a = template.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080", String.class)
      println a
   }
}
```

**But with Spock the application doesn't start (how can I get it to start?):**

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyServer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
class MyTestSpec extends Specification {

   RestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

   def "Do my test"() {
      setup:
      def a = template.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080", String.class)

      expect:
      println a
   }
}
```

For Spock, of course, I have specified the proper dependencies in my Gradle build file:

```
...
dependencies {
   testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
   testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:0.7-groovy-2.0'
}
...
```

Comment: I confidently give the benefit of the doubt that indeed, "with Spock the application doesn't start".  It would be slightly helpful to update here, what detail it is exactly, that reflects that the app didn't start:  Does something initialize null?  Is there some expected logging (maybe by Spring) or output, that does not print by the end of the test run?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is that Spock Spring is looking for Spring's `@ContextConfiguration` annotation and doesn't manage to find it. Strictly speaking `MyTestSpec` *is* annotated with `@ContextConfiguration` as it's a meta-annotation on `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` but Spock Spring doesn't consider meta-annotations as part of its search. There's an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=349) to address this limitation. In the meantime you can work around it.

All that `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is doing  is customising `@ContextConfiguration` with a Boot-specific context loader. This means that you can achieve the same effect by using an appropriately configured `@ContextConfiguration` annotation instead:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = MyServer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
class MyTestSpec extends Specification {
    …
}
```

**Update:** Just to make sure it's clear (and based on the comments, it wasn't), for this to work you need to have `org.spockframework:spock-spring` on the classpath.

Comment: Is there a flag to provide the VM when launching integration tests? I have copied this configuration and my app is not starting. Am I right in deducing that MyServer is the class having the Configuration and EnableAutoConfiguration annotations?

Comment: No flags should be necessary and your deduction about MyServer is correct. You can read more about @ContextConfiguration here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing-annotations-spring. Have you got spock-spring on the classpath?

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson I was just coming back to let people know that spock-spring was necessary in the classpath, and I saw your response. Thanks man!

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it clearer. I've also opened an issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1234) to update the relevant section of the Spring Boot documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-spock)

Answer (score 9):

Ideally you'll use Spring Boot 1.4+ and Spock 1.1+.

Spring Boot added a lot of useful annotations.  In addition to that `@SpringBootTest` that @ignacio.suay mentioned, they also added `@TestConfiguration` which is useful if you want to use Spring mocks in your integration tests instead of Mockito.

If you combine `@TestConfiguration` with the new Spock `DetachedMockFactory`, then you have all of the components you'll need to inject Spock Mocks into your Spring context.

I have a blog post with sample code here: [Spring Integration Testing with Spock Mocks](https://objectpartners.com/2017/04/18/spring-integration-testing-with-spock-mocks/).

The quick and dirty is this

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyIntegrationTest extends Specification {

  @Autowired ExternalRankingService externalRankingServiceMock

  def "GetRank"() {
    when:
    classUnderTest.getRankFor('Bob')

    then:
    1 * externalRankingServiceMock.fetchRank('Bob') >> 5

  }

  @TestConfiguration
  static class Config {
    private DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    @Bean
    ExternalRankingService externalRankingService() {
      factory.Mock(ExternalRankingService)
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
There is [a PR](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/796) to get more native support in Spock for injecting Spock Mocks into the Spring context for integration testing. The new `@SpringBean` and `@SpringSpy` would be like the `@MockBean` and `@SpyBean` annotations

**UPDATE**
Spock 1.2 should now include these changes.  Until the documentation is updated, here is a [preview of the Spock 1.2 Annotations for Spring Integration Testing](https://objectpartners.com/2018/06/14/spock-1-2-annotations-for-spring-integration-testing/) .

Comment: TestConfiguration can be used to define additional beans or
 customizations for a test, mocking is only one of many use cases. You can  simply use spring @MockBean to mock using Mockito....

Comment: @MariuszS This question is about Spock. It would be considered a pretty bad code smell to use Mockito in conjunction with Spock. Spock has mocking build into it.  At the time of this answer, `@MockBean` didn't support Spock Mocks.

Answer (score 5):

In the new Spring Boot version (1.4) instead of using:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyServer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
```

You could use

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServer.class)
```

and you will be able to start the application context and set any dependency.

for further information, please have a look to this example:
http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-do-integration-tests-with-spring-boot-and-spock/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a setup which starts up boot applicaiton and then runs spock tests:

```
class HelloControllerSpec extends Specification {

@Shared
@AutoCleanup
ConfigurableApplicationContext context

void setupSpec() {
    Future future = Executors
            .newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(
            new Callable() {
                @Override
                public ConfigurableApplicationContext call() throws Exception {
                    return (ConfigurableApplicationContext) SpringApplication
                            .run(Application.class)
                }
            })
    context = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}

void "should return pong from /ping"() {
    when:
    ResponseEntity entity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/ping", String.class)

    then:
    entity.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK
    entity.body == 'pong'
}
}
```

And remember to add dependencies to spock and groovy inside `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies
    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.0"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0"
}
```