# How to find port of Spring Boot container when running a spock test using property server.port=0

Tags: testing, port, spring-boot, spock

Given this entry in `application.properties`:

```
server.port=0
```

which causes Spring Boot to chose a random available port, and testing a spring boot web application using spock, how can the spock code know which port to hit?

Normal injection like this:

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
int port;
```

doesn't work with spock.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find the port using this code:

```java
int port = context.embeddedServletContainer.port
```

Which for those interested in the java equivalent is:

```java
int port = ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer)((AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext)context).getEmbeddedServletContainer()).getPort();
```

Here's an abstract class that you can extends which wraps up this initialization of the spring boot application and determines the port:

```java
abstract class SpringBootSpecification extends Specification {

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context

    int port = context.embeddedServletContainer.port

    void launch(Class clazz) {
        Future future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(
                new Callable() {
                    @Override
                    public ConfigurableApplicationContext call() throws Exception {
                        return (ConfigurableApplicationContext) SpringApplication.run(clazz)
                    }
                })
        context = future.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```java
class MySpecification extends SpringBootSpecification {
    void setupSpec() {
        launch(MyLauncher.class)
    }

    String getBody(someParam) {
        ResponseEntity entity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:${port}/somePath/${someParam}", String.class)
        return entity.body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The injection will work with Spock, as long as you've configured your spec class correctly and have `spock-spring` on the classpath. There's a [limitation in Spock Spring](https://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=349) which means it won't bootstrap your Boot application if you use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`. You need to use `@ContextConfiguration` and configure it manually instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405727/integration-test-with-spring-boot-and-spock/24412145#24412145) for the details.

The second part of the problem is that you can't use a GString for the `@Value`. You could escape the `$`, but it's easier to use single quotes:

```groovy
@Value('${local.server.port}')
private int port;
```

Putting this together, you get a spec that looks something like this:

```groovy
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader, classes = SampleSpockTestingApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port=0")
class SampleSpockTestingApplicationSpec extends Specification {

    @Value("\${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    def "The index page has the expected body"() {
        when: "the index page is accessed"
        def response = new TestRestTemplate().getForEntity(
            "http://localhost:$port", String.class);
        then: "the response is OK and the body is welcome"
        response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK
        response.body == 'welcome'
    }
}
```

Also note the use of `@IntegrationTest("server.port=0")` to request a random port be used. It's a nice alternative to configuring it in `application.properties`.

Comment: @SpringApplicationConfiguration seems to be working using Spock 1.0.

Comment: Andy's answer should've been marked as the real answer. His solution for getting port# with the @Value string is much more elegant.

Comment: BTW, @andy-wilkinson, spock-spring now supports `@SpringBootTest` as a single annotation instead of having to combine `@ContextConfiguration`, `@WebAppConfiguration`, and `@IntegrationTests`. So all you have to do is: `@SpringBootTest (webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this too:

```
@Autowired
private org.springframework.core.env.Environment springEnv;
...
springEnv.getProperty("server.port");
```