# How can I avoid Spring Boot from loading EmbeddedWebApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel, spring-boot

I have an Spring Boot integration application with Camel-HTTP. Since Camel-HTTP has a dependency to `geronimo-servlet` Spring Boot is trying to load the web application context.

How can I force Spring to not load the `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext`?

I have tried to exclude all the AutoConfiguration classes found in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web` with the `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ...)` annotation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [SpringApplicationBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html) class to explicitly disable loading a web environment and context,
i.e. in your main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainConfig.class).web(false).run(args);
}
```

Comment: That worked! I was doing the same with `SpringApplication` instead of `SprintApplicationBuilder`, but it was detecting the servlet and creating the web context. With the builder it works fine. Thanks

Comment: This will not work if javax.servlet.Servlet or org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext are in the classpath. Better call contextClass method to specify the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.

Comment: @ConstantinoCronemberger The `web(false)` call is after the `initialize(sources)` method, which is called as part of the SAB/SA constructor so this should not be the case?

Comment: In my case the webEnvironment was overwritten by the "web-environment" property in the application.yml class. In my case I really have a web application, but I wanted to create another entry point to be able to run a specific part of the code without starting Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationCtxtLoader.class, classes = annotatedClass.class)
```

The `annotatedClass.class` are the class that are [annotated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html), for instance with: `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253893/forcing-spring-boot-to-not-use-embeddedwebapplicationcontext) answer this is the suggested approach for testing purposes, but I think it might help you

Comment: That may be work for tests, but not for the Spring Boot application itself