# Spring boot and Spock integration test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spock

I am new to Spring boot and while testing the REST endpoint using SPOCK , came across with the question [#24405727](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405727/integration-test-with-spring-boot-and-spock)
I have tried the exact configuration but getting the below exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The WebApplicationContext for test context [TestContext@21a722ef testClass = HelloControllerSpec, testInstance = com.hello.HelloControllerSpec@63e68a2b, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3479404a testClass = HelloControllerSpec, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]] must be configured with a MockServletContext.
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptSetupMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Below is my Groovy spock specification

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
class HelloControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def "Greeting test"() {
        when:
        ResponseEntity entity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:8080", String.class);
         
        then:
        entity.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK
     }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that `ServletTestExecutionListener` has been registered. It's intended for setting up a mock Servlet environment which you don't need as you're using a full-blown web stack. Unfortunately, from what you posted, I can't tell why it's being registered. Debugging with a breakpoint on `TestContextManager`'s `registerTestExecutionListeners` method should help you to figure it out.

Comment: The issue got resolved by explicitly adding the @TestExecutionListeners([DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class]). Is this needed? why the automatic configuration did not take care of this?

Comment: Did you find out what was registering the incorrect defaults?

Comment: As per the debug statement, it was going to the block if (declaringClass == null) {
   if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("@TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [" + clazz + "]: using defaults.");
   }
   classesList.addAll(getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClasses());
   defaultListeners = true;
  }