# How to configure Spock test to load Spring Context (for @Autowired)?

Tags: java, spring, spock, applicationcontext

I have such `Application` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@EnableJpaRepositories("ibd.jpa")
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

I also have this `UserService` class (it is discovered by  `@EnableJpaRepositories("ibd.jpa")`):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public User createUser(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String password){
    return userRepository.save(new User(login,password));
}
```

And I try to test in this `UserService`:

```
@ContextConfiguration
class UserServiceTest extends Specification {

@Autowired
def UserService userService


def "if User not exists 404 status in response sent and corresponding message shown"() {
    when: 'rest account url is hit'
    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(userService).build()
        def response = mockMvc.perform(get('/user?login=wrongusername&password=wrongPassword')).andReturn().response
    then:
        response.status == NOT_FOUND.value()
        response.errorMessage == "Login or password is not correct"

}
```

But the issue is:
**UserService in test is `null` - it doesn't get successfully `@Autowired`; that shows that the Spring Context didn't load.  How can I configure for successful Autowiring?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of prior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405727/integration-test-with-spring-boot-and-spock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was solved by:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
```

and usage of RestTemplate

[as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654842/spring-boot-and-spock-integration-test?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on this since the bounty wanted some elaboration: Spring doesn't wire up beans by default in unit tests.  That's why those annotations are needed.  I'll try to break them down a little bit:

- [@IntegrationTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/IntegrationTest.html) (which is now deprecated in favor of [@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) ) from the docs:

> - Uses SpringBootContextLoader as the default ContextLoader when no specific @ContextConfiguration(loader=...) is defined.
> - Automatically searches for a @SpringBootConfiguration when nested @Configuration is not used, and no explicit classes are specified.

- [@WebAppConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/WebAppConfiguration.html) adds the application context, and must be used with...
- [@ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) actually determines how to load the "class-level" metadata.

Without these annotations, Spring doesn't wire up the beans necessary for your test configuration.  This is partially for performance reasons (most tests don't need the context configured).

Comment: could you please add some notes about using Spring (not SpringBoot)?

Comment: @ДмитрийКулешов The latter two annotations are not specific to Spring Boot.  I think the first one could be replaced with something like "@RunWith" but I'm not sure as I've only ever used these with Spring Boot.  What are you specifically trying to do?