# WebApplicationContext does not Autowire when injecting in Spock Specification

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spock, mockmvc

Although I followed the Spring Boot Guide, when trying:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=MainWebApplication.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")

class FirstSpec extends Specification{
  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

  @Shared
  MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build()

  def "Root returns 200 - OK"(){

      when:
      response = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))

      then:
      response.andExpect(status().isOk())
  }
}
```

I just get the message that a WebApplicationContext just is not injected. I do have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-maven</artifactId>
        <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my .pom, also, just as the guide advises, yet still no success. Anything I am missing? I need the app context so all the beans are injected. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405727/integration-test-with-spring-boot-and-spock/24412145#24412145?

Comment: Unlikely, since I tried that workaround with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try moving the mockMvc construction to the `setup` method?

```
def setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use SpringBean annotation available in Spock 1.2: https://objectpartners.com/2018/06/14/spock-1-2-annotations-for-spring-integration-testing/

it could be easier with this :

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=MainWebApplication.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")

class FirstSpec extends Specification{
  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc

  // if any service to mock
  @SpringBean
  MyService myService

  def "Root returns 200 - OK"(){

      when:
      response = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))

      then:
      response.andExpect(status().isOk())
  }
}
```

If you don't want to mock your services you can use directly @SpringBootTest which does the same job with only one annotation

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")

class FirstSpec extends Specification{
  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc

  // if any service to mock
  @SpringBean
  MyService myService

  def "Root returns 200 - OK"(){

      when:
      response = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))

      then:
      response.andExpect(status().isOk())
  }
}
```

Comment: Vincent, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I added more details about my answer thanks for your feedback